# How do i use Google maps in my android application

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I want to include google maps to my application that i'm developing these days.But i cannot install Google play library because it's not shown in my extras folder in SDK

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: show us your code, what have you tried? Have you searched on Google for something like 'Google Maps Android development' then tried some of the tutorials and samples? As it is your question might be deleted as off topic or low quality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning of Google Maps

- These are two important steps you should follow*

**1. Download Google Play Services**
Google made new Maps V2 API as a part of Google Play Services SDK. So before we start developing maps we need to download google play services from SDK manger. You can open SDK manager either from Eclipse or from android sdk folder.

**Open Eclipse ⇒ Windows ⇒ Android SDK Manager** and check whether you have already downloaded Google Play Services or not under Extras section. If not select play services and install the package.

**2. Import Google Play Services into Eclipse**
After downloading play services we need to import it to Eclipse which will be used as a library for our maps project.

1. In Eclipse goto **File ⇒ Import ⇒ Android ⇒ Existing Android Code Into Workspace**
2. Click on Browse and select Google Play Services project from your android sdk folder. You can locate play services library project from
   **android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib**

**Are you a fresher learn from this link Best Tutorial With Source code and Explanation**

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: i don't see Play services anywhere in my SDK

Comment: what is the version of SDK u have . its better u have buit in tools with sdk 19 or sdk 20

Comment: Open your Android SDK Manager
install Android sdk platform tools 20
go down See Extras
select Google Play Service and intall

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use the Google Maps API v2, this will help you integrate the Google Maps in your own application. If you want steps about it, I advise you to follow [this Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html), you'll find everyting you need and more ! =)